# Avoiding content duplication. SEO for similiar sites with different branding

Tags: seo

I have a single site but it is marketed regionally with slightly different brand names. I have a xyz-example.com for asia, xyz.com for europe,  xyz-supercompany.com for africa etc.

I have both english and french versions of the site, each site is identical apart from the branding.

I know I should use canonical url to point back to the main domain (xyz.com), but AFIAK cross domain canonical urls are only supported by Google?

How else can I try minimize being penalized for duplicate content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to not get done for content duplication is not to duplicate your content. (sorry I know its obvious)

I cant believe that the content served to a Asia, Europe and Africa should be the same, even if the product is the same and you are talking about the product always in English and French

The way you market to each area across the world is different and will need tailoring to each market, so change your content and tailor it to your different global markets and then you wont have content duplication.

If your content is the same then you only need one site.